# Why won't any of my IF/ELSEIF statements execute?

Tags: excel, vba, subroutine

Below I my code written in VBA for excel. My main concern is why none of this will execute. Whenever I change a cell value it doesn't go through any of the if else statements. My understanding is that this subroutine should execute whenever a cell value within the worksheet is changed. I then use if else statements to determine which cells are being change, then perform the correct calculations. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    '////////////////////COLUMN C & E CALCULATION STEPS///////////////////////////
If (Target.Column = 3) Then
    If (Target.Row = 11) Then
        Range("D11").Value = Range("C11").Value / Range("C5").Value
    ElseIf (13 <= Target.Row <= 19) Then
        Range("D13").Value = Range("C13").Value / Range("C5").Value
        Range("D14").Value = Range("C14").Value / Range("C5").Value
        Range("D15").Value = Range("C15").Value / Range("C5").Value
        Range("D16").Value = Range("C16").Value / Range("C5").Value
        Range("D17").Value = Range("C17").Value / Range("C5").Value
        Range("D18").Value = Range("C18").Value / Range("C5").Value
        Range("D19").Value = Range("C19").Value / Range("C5").Value
    ElseIf (21 <= Target.Row <= 27) Then
        Range("D21").Value = Range("C21").Value / Range("C5").Value
        Range("D22").Value = Range("C22").Value / Range("C5").Value
        Range("D23").Value = Range("C23").Value / Range("C5").Value
        Range("D24").Value = Range("C24").Value / Range("C5").Value
        Range("D25").Value = Range("C25").Value / Range("C5").Value
        Range("D26").Value = Range("C26").Value / Range("C5").Value
        Range("D27").Value = Range("C27").Value / Range("C5").Value
    ElseIf (29 <= Target.Row <= 30) Then
        Range("D29").Value = Range("C29").Value / Range("C5").Value
        Range("D30").Value = Range("C30").Value / Range("C5").Value
    ElseIf (32 <= Target.Row <= 33) Then
        Range("D32").Value = Range("C32").Value / Range("C5").Value
        Range("D33").Value = Range("C33").Value / Range("C5").Value
    ElseIf (Target.Row = 35) Then
        Range("D35").Value = Range("C35").Value / Range("C5").Value
    ElseIf (37 <= Target.Row <= 39) Then
        Range("D37").Value = Range("C37").Value / Range("C5").Value
        Range("D38").Value = Range("C38").Value / Range("C5").Value
        Range("D39").Value = Range("C39").Value / Range("C5").Value
    ElseIf (Target.Row = 41) Then
        Range("D41").Value = Range("C41").Value / Range("C5").Value
    ElseIf (43 <= Target.Row <= 44) Then
        Range("D43").Value = Range("C43").Value / Range("C5").Value
        Range("D44").Value = Range("C44").Value / Range("C5").Value
    ElseIf (46 <= Target.Row <= 47) Then
        Range("D46").Value = Range("C46").Value / Range("C5").Value
        Range("D47").Value = Range("C47").Value / Range("C5").Value
    Else
    End If
ElseIf (Target.Column = 5) Then
    If (Target.Row = 11) Then
        Range("F11").Value = Range("E11").Value / Range("C5").Value
    ElseIf (13 <= Target.Row <= 19) Then
        Range("F13").Value = Range("E13").Value / Range("C5").Value
        Range("F14").Value = Range("E14").Value / Range("C5").Value
        Range("F15").Value = Range("E15").Value / Range("C5").Value
        Range("F16").Value = Range("E16").Value / Range("C5").Value
        Range("F17").Value = Range("E17").Value / Range("C5").Value
        Range("F18").Value = Range("E18").Value / Range("C5").Value
        Range("F19").Value = Range("E19").Value / Range("C5").Value
    ElseIf (21 <= Target.Row <= 27) Then
        Range("F21").Value = Range("E21").Value / Range("C5").Value
        Range("F22").Value = Range("E22").Value / Range("C5").Value
        Range("F23").Value = Range("E23").Value / Range("C5").Value
        Range("F24").Value = Range("E24").Value / Range("C5").Value
        Range("F25").Value = Range("E25").Value / Range("C5").Value
        Range("F26").Value = Range("E26").Value / Range("C5").Value
        Range("F27").Value = Range("E27").Value / Range("C5").Value
    ElseIf (29 <= Target.Row <= 30) Then
        Range("F29").Value = Range("E29").Value / Range("C5").Value
        Range("F30").Value = Range("E30").Value / Range("C5").Value
    ElseIf (32 <= Target.Row <= 33) Then
        Range("F32").Value = Range("E32").Value / Range("C5").Value
        Range("F33").Value = Range("E33").Value / Range("C5").Value
    ElseIf (Target.Row = 35) Then
        Range("F35").Value = Range("E35").Value / Range("C5").Value
    ElseIf (37 <= Target.Row <= 39) Then
        Range("F37").Value = Range("E37").Value / Range("C5").Value
        Range("F38").Value = Range("E38").Value / Range("C5").Value
        Range("F39").Value = Range("E39").Value / Range("C5").Value
    ElseIf (Target.Row = 41) Then
        Range("F41").Value = Range("E41").Value / Range("C5").Value
    ElseIf (43 <= Target.Row <= 44) Then
        Range("F43").Value = Range("E43").Value / Range("C5").Value
        Range("F44").Value = Range("E44").Value / Range("C5").Value
    ElseIf (46 <= Target.Row <= 47) Then
        Range("F46").Value = Range("E46").Value / Range("C5").Value
        Range("F47").Value = Range("E47").Value / Range("C5").Value
    Else
    End If

    '////////////////////COLUMN D & F CALCULATION STEPS///////////////////////////
    ElseIf (Target.Column = 4) Then
    If (Target.Row = 11) Then
        Range("C11").Value = Range("D11").Value * Range("C5").Value
    ElseIf (13 <= Target.Row <= 19) Then
        Range("C13").Value = Range("D13").Value * Range("C5").Value
        Range("C14").Value = Range("D14").Value * Range("C5").Value
        Range("C15").Value = Range("D15").Value * Range("C5").Value
        Range("C16").Value = Range("D16").Value * Range("C5").Value
        Range("C17").Value = Range("D17").Value * Range("C5").Value
        Range("C18").Value = Range("D18").Value * Range("C5").Value
        Range("C19").Value = Range("D19").Value * Range("C5").Value
    ElseIf (21 <= Target.Row <= 27) Then
        Range("C21").Value = Range("D21").Value * Range("C5").Value
        Range("C22").Value = Range("D22").Value * Range("C5").Value
        Range("C23").Value = Range("D23").Value * Range("C5").Value
        Range("C24").Value = Range("D24").Value * Range("C5").Value
        Range("C25").Value = Range("D25").Value * Range("C5").Value
        Range("C26").Value = Range("D26").Value * Range("C5").Value
        Range("C27").Value = Range("D27").Value * Range("C5").Value
    ElseIf (29 <= Target.Row <= 30) Then
        Range("C29").Value = Range("D29").Value * Range("C5").Value
        Range("C30").Value = Range("D30").Value * Range("C5").Value
    ElseIf (32 <= Target.Row <= 33) Then
        Range("C32").Value = Range("D32").Value * Range("C5").Value
        Range("C33").Value = Range("D33").Value * Range("C5").Value
    ElseIf (Target.Row = 35) Then
        Range("C35").Value = Range("D35").Value * Range("C5").Value
    ElseIf (37 <= Target.Row <= 39) Then
        Range("C37").Value = Range("D37").Value * Range("C5").Value
        Range("C38").Value = Range("D38").Value * Range("C5").Value
        Range("C39").Value = Range("D39").Value * Range("C5").Value
    ElseIf (Target.Row = 41) Then
        Range("C41").Value = Range("D41").Value * Range("C5").Value
    ElseIf (43 <= Target.Row <= 44) Then
        Range("C43").Value = Range("D43").Value * Range("C5").Value
        Range("C44").Value = Range("D44").Value * Range("C5").Value
    ElseIf (46 <= Target.Row <= 47) Then
        Range("C46").Value = Range("D46").Value * Range("C5").Value
        Range("C47").Value = Range("D47").Value * Range("C5").Value
    Else
    End If
ElseIf (Target.Column = 6) Then
    If (Target.Row = 11) Then
        Range("E11").Value = Range("F11").Value * Range("C5").Value
    ElseIf (13 <= Target.Row <= 19) Then
        Range("E13").Value = Range("F13").Value * Range("C5").Value
        Range("E14").Value = Range("F14").Value * Range("C5").Value
        Range("E15").Value = Range("E15").Value * Range("C5").Value
        Range("E16").Value = Range("F16").Value * Range("C5").Value
        Range("E17").Value = Range("F17").Value * Range("C5").Value
        Range("E18").Value = Range("F18").Value * Range("C5").Value
        Range("E19").Value = Range("F19").Value * Range("C5").Value
    ElseIf (21 <= Target.Row <= 27) Then
        Range("E21").Value = Range("F21").Value * Range("C5").Value
        Range("E22").Value = Range("F22").Value * Range("C5").Value
        Range("E23").Value = Range("F23").Value * Range("C5").Value
        Range("E24").Value = Range("F24").Value * Range("C5").Value
        Range("E25").Value = Range("F25").Value * Range("C5").Value
        Range("E26").Value = Range("F26").Value * Range("C5").Value
        Range("E27").Value = Range("F27").Value * Range("C5").Value
    ElseIf (29 <= Target.Row <= 30) Then
        Range("E29").Value = Range("F29").Value * Range("C5").Value
        Range("E30").Value = Range("F30").Value * Range("C5").Value
    ElseIf (32 <= Target.Row <= 33) Then
        Range("E32").Value = Range("F32").Value * Range("C5").Value
        Range("E33").Value = Range("F33").Value * Range("C5").Value
    ElseIf (Target.Row = 35) Then
        Range("E35").Value = Range("E35").Value * Range("C5").Value
    ElseIf (37 <= Target.Row <= 39) Then
        Range("E37").Value = Range("F37").Value * Range("C5").Value
        Range("E38").Value = Range("F38").Value * Range("C5").Value
        Range("E39").Value = Range("F39").Value * Range("C5").Value
    ElseIf (Target.Row = 41) Then
        Range("E41").Value = Range("F41").Value * Range("C5").Value
    ElseIf (43 <= Target.Row <= 44) Then
        Range("E43").Value = Range("F43").Value * Range("C5").Value
        Range("E44").Value = Range("F44").Value * Range("C5").Value
    ElseIf (46 <= Target.Row <= 47) Then
        Range("E46").Value = Range("F46").Value * Range("C5").Value
        Range("E47").Value = Range("F47").Value * Range("C5").Value
    Else
    End If
    Else
    End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: If you change a value in Column C, this doesn't fire at all? Put a Break on the `If (Target.Row = 11)` to see if it even makes it to that when you change, say C2.  Also, make sure this code is in the *Worksheet* module of the sheet you expect it to run on.

Comment: The event works for any cell in the sheet, but your code will run only for cells modified on columns C:C. (column 3). Most of your conditions are wrongly written and they are every time true, except the case of row 13...

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the `Select Case` attempt instead of posting in a comment, thanks!

Comment: When someone someone provides an answer that solves your problem,  you should accept it, (click the tick), not edit the answer into the Q

Answer (score 2):

VBA doesn't handle `x <= y <= z` as you might expect. It evaluates `x <= y` first, and then compares the *result* (Boolean) to `z`.

`Select Case` is much better for situations like this:

```
Select Case Target.Row
     Case 11
         ' do something
     Case 13 to 19
         ' do something else
     Case 21 to 27
         ' do the next thing 
     ' and so on
End Select
```

Also important: disable events to avoid re-triggering the event:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
     On Error GoTo SafeExit:
     Application.EnableEvents = False

     ... your code

SafeExit:
     Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Other way around.  it resolve right to left.  first `y<=z` then compares that boolean to `x`

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to try and see if this is possible with the same nested logic that I was using with the if else statements.

Comment: @ScottCraner - that's what I originally thought, but could not replicate that in testing. For example, `? 5 <= 6 <= 7` returns `True`, but `? 5 <= (6 <= 7)` returns `False`. Shouldn't they both be `False` if it evaluates right-to-left? Or am I missing something?

Comment: You may be correct.  `? 1=-1=true` returns False but `? 1=1=true` returns true.

Comment: But `? True=1=1` returns false.

Comment: and `? 1=1=-1` returns true, so it must be left to right.  I am sooooo confused.

Comment: @ScottCraner `CBool(-1)` = `True`.

Comment: And `True=1` returns `False`.

Comment: I know true = -1, I always thought it resolved right to left. I am confused on that point.

Comment: In my mind I thought the same, but it looks like it's actually left to right.

Comment: So I used select case and still no luck. I'm going to try it on an individual cell. And see if that makes a difference

Comment: Just to check - in the immediate window type `Application.EnableEvents = True` and hit Enter.

Comment: Just tried with individual cell, no luck. Attached is the code.        Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'////////////////////COLUMN C & E CALCULATION STEPS///////////////////////////
On Error GoTo SafeExit:
     Application.EnableEvents = False
     
    Select Case Target.Column
        Case 3
            Select Case Target.Row
                Case 11
                    Range("D11").Value = Range("C11").Value / Range("C5").Value
            End Select
    End Select
    
SafeExit:
     Application.EnableEvents = True
     
End Sub

Comment: `?True=1=1` => `-1=1=1` => `False=1` => `False`; `?1=1=-1` => `True=-1` => `True=True`. It is left to right but as BigBen notes, VBA evaluates it as Boolean expressions which can then get converted back to integers. Loosey-goosey pant-falling implicit conversions make for much illogic.

Comment: YESS! So i actually just tried it in a new excel sheet and the program works. I only did it with one celll and did not add the Application.EnableEvents = True statement. I will update if it works with the whole excel sheet. Thanks!